# Decode Float (serialized as double)

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to decode a bytes array in Python 3.8 where the sending interface spec states the format is "float (serialized as double)".

Using a sample bytes array received from the interface, this is the result i get

```
>>> import struct
>>> bytes_arr = b'\xbf\xe9\x99\x99\xa0\x00\x00\x00'
>>> print(struct.unpack('d', bytes_arr))
(3.40792534166e-312,)
```

The parent application (displaying the same data i am receiving over the interface) states the answer to be `-0.8`. This is obviously rounded but a different decode.

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value is in [big-endian](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) format:

```
>>> print(struct.unpack('>d', bytes_arr))
(-0.800000011920929,)
```